# Server says the request went through but client says error

Tags: ajax, node.js

I am building a web app and for the server I am using nodejs and express. When I make a request to the server just from the browser it works fine, but when I try an ajax request from the client it registers on the server, but gives me an error on the client. Here is what I am using for the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    crossDomain: true,          
    success: function(response) {},

    error: function(response){
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

on server side, when you send the request... set header of response to allow cors:
something like this >>

```
res.writeHead(200,{
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
});
```

In place of '*', you can specify a set of urls, you want to server response to...